Browser EventLoop prevents window load event from firing when advanced by an async substlecrypto call
Why is it happening and how to fix it? To reproduce comment/uncomment generateKey call and watch the event handler (you might want to put into a module (which is how I use it) or execute is as part async IIFE - post updated to give the exact repro). The behavior is observed in Chrome v.128.0.6613.138.
Note: wrapping generateKey inside a nested IIFE (and thus lowering its execution priority) * fixes * the event handling, but I need my keys beforehand. I understand that it's a dreadful approach from user experience point of view, but ignoring the registered handler doesn't seem like an adequate measure neither.
(async () => {

    const keys = await window.crypto.subtle.generateKey(
        {
            name: "ECDSA",
            namedCurve: "P-256"
        },
        true,
        ["sign", "verify"]
    );

    window.addEventListener("load", () => {
        debugger;
        console.info("Fired");
    });


})();


You have to add the load event listener before the window is loaded. But while you await the async generateKey(), the window will finish loading, so the load event has already fired.

Why don't you call generateKey() inside the load listener?

you are missing the point, the actual use case is way more complex, I simplified it to show the problem in a nutshell. The question was why it does it happen. I have a few ways to fix it with each of them leading to some sort of a compromise. The ultimate goal is to understand WHY it happens.

@Barmar  "so the load event has already fired" - why did it not trigger the event handler? with all my respect. also - please pay attention to "await" the actual event subscription shouldn't have happened until the crypto call is finished. We are guessing here, I need an expert opinion.

Yes, I'm doing some guessing. It didn't trigger the event handler because you hadn't added it yet. The order I'm assuming is: call generateKey(), load event fires (calling any event listeners), generateKey() finishes, call addEventListener().

Pretty much. I'm guessing myself, but looks like a weirdo related to event loop. as I can defo see the keys being gen'ed before the addEventListner call.

What you're ignoring is that when you call an async function it doesn't block anything. The page finishes loading and the load event is triggered. But await blocks your function until generateKey() finishes.

Of course the key is gen'ed before addEventListener(), because you have await blocking blocking this function. It doesn't block anything else.

that's why I wonder why the handler doesn't get triggered. You may question the approach in general, but no matter what it shouldn't have swallowed the handler.

The handler doesn't get triggered because you're adding it after the event happens. You have to add an event listener before the event, it won't go back in time.

The event happens while this function is awaiting the key generation that happens asynchronously. At least that's consistent with your symptoms.

this makes sense. so window load event aren't safe to be used with the blocking constructs. right?

you can't stop the world. after all, which is what I seemed to try doing.

What you need to remember is that await doesn't block everything, it just suspends that one function. Everything else continues.

I think that was it bud. In a way it is a failed promise - you'd be expecting it to wait but nada. lol. Anyway I know how to get outta there.

@Bramar - still if that can't hold up the execution just fire it before the awaitable. But it does get suppressed altogether, which is smuckedup to my oppinion.
